# How to config Springboot with Google cloud platform API vesion

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, vision-api

I am building springboot application that uses Google Cloud Platform Vision API, to use Google cloud platform, the credentials is required so I am trying to configure it but it does not talk it and talk the credentials way in the code, I want to use the credentials that into application.properties, how to do that?

Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class VisionConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public CloudVisionTemplate cloudVisionTemplate() throws IOException {
        Credentials credentials = new Credentials();
        return new CloudVisionTemplate(imageAnnotatorClient(new DefaultCredentialsProvider(() -> credentials)));
    }

    @Bean
    ImageAnnotatorClient imageAnnotatorClient(CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) throws IOException {
        ImageAnnotatorSettings settings = ImageAnnotatorSettings
                .newBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
        return ImageAnnotatorClient.create(settings);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=credentials.json
```

and I put the credentials json file under resource folder

could any one help?

Comment: Will you run your app on Google Cloud?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No, I just want to use Vision API

Comment: Ok, run elsewhere? On AWS? Azure? On your computer? My question are focus to remove the credential file which is a security hole. And all the previously named platforms do not need a key, and you can easily solve your issue by removing it!